# What is faster: an index-array or getters and variables?

Tags: php, oop

I am trying to figure out what should be considered better for performance:

I have a bunch of objects that contain a lot of page-data.
A few examples of the data that an object can have:

- filepath of PHP-file for includes
- CSS filepath
- JavaScript filepath
- Meta data of the page

The object is specific for each type of content. I have an interface that defines the render-function. Each object implements this function differently.

**Example:**

```
class PhpFragment extends FragmentBase {
  public function render() {
    //... render output for this type of data
  }
}
```

I am currently using a parent-object that contains variables that can contain multiple object of the type mentioned above. The object looks something like this:

```
class pageData {
  protected $CSS;
  protected $PHP;
  protected $JS;
  protected $Meta;
  protected etc...

  public function getCSS() {
      return $this->CSS;
  }

  public function getPHP() {
      return $this->PHP;
  }

  public function getJS() {
      return $this->JS;
  }
}
```

Whenever I load in a page, I walk through a template and render the data of each object that matches the tag in the template.

**For example**: If a template has a line where CSS is needed, I call the getCSS function of the pageData which returns an array of objects. Foreach of these objects I call the render function and add the data in the page.

### What do I want?

I want to get rid of these fixed variables in the pageData object to be able to use my design as dynamically as possible. I want the pageData object to disappear and just have an array of different fragment-objects.

To achieve this, I need to replace the `get-functions` in the pageData with something clever?

My top priority is performance, so I thought I'd look through all the objects once to get all the different types, and put all the types as key in the array, the value of the array will then be a subarray that contains the correct key to the objects that match the type.

What I was wondering, before I start changing the design entirely, is this faster?

Comment: From a performance point of view both alternatives show such little difference that you should not take that into consideration. Much more important is that it is easy to read, understand and modify the code.

Comment: 1) Benchmark it. You'll find that the practical difference will likely be so minuscule as to be irrelevant. 2) Design your API for robustness and extensibility first, performance details second (especially if the performance difference is minuscule).

Comment: @deceze: when benchmarking, it's important to compare RO access to RW, the copy-on-write mechanism might skew the results if the OP only tests array performance WRT reading values, writing to an array argument is where arrays suddenly become more expensive than expected. However, I do agree with you: _"more expensive"_ is a bit of moot point, those couple of milliseconds are unlikely to be the bottleneck

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the right place to ask this question (it's more a code-review question IMO). Anyway, here's a couple of thoughts I'd consider if I were you:

### What are objects

Objects are units of functionality, or entities that represent a specific set of values. DTO's (like your pageData class) serves one purpouse: to group, and represent a set of values that belong together. The fact that a class has a type (type-hints) and an interface makes a code-base testable, easier to understand, maintain, debug, and document.
At first glance, a simple DTO isn't too different from a simple array, and yes, objects have a ***marginal*** performance cost.

The question you need to ask is whether or not you want to shave of those 1 or 2 ms per request at the cost of: increased development time, less testable, more error prone, and harder to maintain code. I'd argue that for this reason alone, DTO's make more sense than arrays

### pre-declared properties are fast

If you want an object that is as dynamic as possible, then PHP offers you to possibility to add properties to instances on the fly:

```
Class Foo{}
$x = new Foo;
$x->bar = 'new property';
echo $x->bar;//echoes new property
```

So in essence, objects are just as flexible as arrays. However, properties that weren't declared beforehand are (again ***marginally***) slower than predeclared properties.

When a class definition declares 3 properties, these properties are stored in a hash table. When accessing a member of an instance, this hashtable will be checked first. Internally, these hashtable lookups are O(1), If no properties were declared, any *"dynamic"* property is stored in a second hash table. Lookups on this fallback HT are *O(n)*. Not terrible, but worse than they need be.

In addition to dynamic properties being less performant, they're also always public, so you have no control over their values (they can be reassigned elsewhere), and they are, of course, susceptible to human error (typo's):

```
$x = new Foo;
$x->foo = 'Set the value of foo';
echo $x->fo;//typo...
```

### Getters and setters are good

The methods you have now don't *do* anything, true enough, but consider this:

```
class User
{
    protected $email;
    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Invalid email');
        }
        $this->email = $email;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

A setter like this not only allows me to control/check when and where a property is set, but also to validate the data that someone is trying to assign to it. You can *validate* the data. You can ensure that, no matter what, if you receive an instance of `User`, the email will either be null, or a *valid email address*.

There are many more reasons why objects make more sense than arrays, but these alone, to me at least, outweigh the benefits of 2ms/req performance gain.

### If performance is such an issue, why not write in a faster language?

If all you're after is performance, you might want to look into languages that outperform PHP to begin with. Don't get me wrong: I honestly like PHP, but it's just a fact that, for example, Go can do the same thing, only faster.

### Pass by value, copy-on-write, and (almost) pass by reference

Arrays are, essentially, scalar values. Pass an array to a function, and any changes made to that array inside the function doesn't change the array you passed to that method. Objects are (sort-of) passed by reference. That's to say: objects are passed by identifier.
Say you have an instance of `Foo`. The Zend engine will assign a unique ID to that instance (eg 123). When you call a function and pass that instance, internally, you'll pass the identifier of that object to the method not the object itself.

This has several implications: When changing the state of the instance, PHP doesn't have to make a copy of the object: it just uses the ID to get the `zval` (internal representation of a PHP variable), and operates on the same piece of memory. The net result: you're passing a simple value (an int), and whatever happens to the object, wherever it happens, the state is shared throughout.

Arrays are different: Passing an array is (sort-of) passing a *copy* of that value. In reality, PHP is clever enough to pass a reference to the existing array, but once you start reassigning values, PHP does *have* to create a copy. This is the copy-on-write mechanism. Put simply, the idea is: do not create needless copies of values, unless you have to:

```
function foo(array $data)
{
    $x = $data[0];//read, no copy of argument is required
    $data[1] = $x * $data[3];//now, we're altering the argument, a copy is created
}
$data = [1, 2, 3, 4];
foo($data);//passes reference
```

Depending on *how* you use the arrays or objects you pass to functions, one might perform better than the other. On the whole: passing an array that you'll only use to *read* values will most likely outperform passing an object. However, if you start operating on the array/object, an object might turn out to outperform arrays...

## TL;DR

Yes, arrays are generally faster than objects. But they're less safe, pretty much impossible to test, harder to maintain an non-communicative (`public function doStuff(array $data)` doesn't tell me as much as `public function doStuff(User $data)`).

Owing to the copy-on-write and the way instances are passed to functions, it's impossible to say which will be faster with absolute certainty. It really boils down to what you do: is the array fairly small, and are you only reading its values, then it's probably going to be faster than objects.

The moment you start operating on the data, it's entirely possible objects might prove to be faster.

---

I can't just leave it there without at least mentioning that old mantra:

## Premature optimization is the root of all evil

Switching from objects to arrays for performance sake does smell of micro-optimization. If you have in fact reached the point that there's nothing else to optimize but these kinds of trivial things, then the project is either a small one; or you're the first person to actually work on a big project and actually **finish** it. In all other cases, you shouldn't really be wasting time on this kind of optimization.

Things that are far more important to profile, and then optimize are:

- Caching (opcache, memcache, ...)
- Disk IO (including files, autoloader mechanisms)
- Resource management: open file pointers, DB connections (when to connect, when to close connections)
- If you're using a traditional SQL DB: queries... The vast majority of PHP applications can benefit a lot by having a DBA look at the queries and actually optimize those
- Server setup
- ...

Only if you've gone through this list, and more, could you perhaps consider thinking about some micro optimization. That is of course, if by then you haven't encountered any bugs...

Comment:  Fantastic response.

Comment: @deceze: thanks, somewhat incomplete, but I didn't want to re-write the PHP internals book here :)